# How to add multiple entries to MS-Word "Math AutoCorrect"?

Tags: microsoft-word, unicode, latex

In MS-Word **Math AutoCorrect** there are entries for all alphabets in *Script* type as below -

[image]

Say, I want to add a similar suite to represent vectors with all the alphabets. Currently I can do it one entry at a time like the entry for `\vectorx` shown below -

[image]

**How can I do it quickly, at one go, for all the alphabets - `\vectora`, `\vectorb`, and so on all the way till `\vectorz`?**